# Unable to use EcsTaskRole inside task to get s3 buckets

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, boto3

I have an ECS Fargate task running, having a task role with following policy:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Action": [
                "ecs:*",
                "ec2:*",
                "elasticloadbalancing:*",
                "ecr:*",
                "cloudwatch:*",
                "s3:*",
                "rds:*",
                "logs:*",
                "elasticache:*",
                "secretsmanager:*"
            ],
            "Resource": "*",
            "Effect": "Allow"
        },
        {
            "Action": [
                "ssmmessages:CreateControlChannel",
                "ssmmessages:CreateDataChannel",
                "ssmmessages:OpenControlChannel",
                "ssmmessages:OpenDataChannel"
            ],
            "Resource": "*",
            "Effect": "Allow"
        },
        {
            "Action": "logs:DescribeLogGroups",
            "Resource": "*",
            "Effect": "Allow"
        },
        {
            "Action": [
                "logs:CreateLogStream",
                "logs:DescribeLogStreams",
                "logs:PutLogEvents"
            ],
            "Resource": "*",
            "Effect": "Allow"
        }
    ]
}
```

This is how my containerdefinition.json looks like

```
{
    "taskDefinitionArn": "arn:aws:ecs:eu-west-1:account-id:task-definition/application:13",
    "containerDefinitions": [
        {
            "name": "application",
            "image": "boohoo:latest",
            "cpu": 256,
            "memory": 512,
            "memoryReservation": 256,
            "links": [],
            "portMappings": [
                {
                    "containerPort": 8000,
                    "hostPort": 8000,
                    "protocol": "tcp"
                }
            ],
            "essential": true,
            "entryPoint": [],
            "command": [
                "pipenv",
                "run",
                "prod"
            ],
            "environment": [],
            "environmentFiles": [],
            "mountPoints": [],
            "volumesFrom": [],
            "secrets": [],
            "user": "uwsgi",
            "dnsServers": [],
            "dnsSearchDomains": [],
            "extraHosts": [],
            "dockerSecurityOptions": [],
            "dockerLabels": {},
            "ulimits": [],
            "logConfiguration": {
                "logDriver": "awslogs",
                "options": {
                    "awslogs-group": "Cluster/services/logs/",
                    "awslogs-region": "eu-west-1",
                    "awslogs-stream-prefix": "application"
                },
                "secretOptions": []
            },
            "systemControls": []
        }
    ],
    "family": "application",
    "taskRoleArn": "arn:aws:iam::account-id:role/task-role",
    "executionRoleArn": "arn:aws:iam::account-id:role/task-execution-role",
    "networkMode": "awsvpc",
    "revision": 13,
    "volumes": [],
    "status": "ACTIVE",
    "requiresAttributes": [
        {
            "name": "com.amazonaws.ecs.capability.logging-driver.awslogs"
        },
        {
            "name": "ecs.capability.execution-role-awslogs"
        },
        {
            "name": "com.amazonaws.ecs.capability.ecr-auth"
        },
        {
            "name": "com.amazonaws.ecs.capability.docker-remote-api.1.19"
        },
        {
            "name": "ecs.capability.secrets.asm.environment-variables"
        },
        {
            "name": "com.amazonaws.ecs.capability.docker-remote-api.1.17"
        },
        {
            "name": "com.amazonaws.ecs.capability.docker-remote-api.1.21"
        },
        {
            "name": "com.amazonaws.ecs.capability.task-iam-role"
        },
        {
            "name": "ecs.capability.execution-role-ecr-pull"
        },
        {
            "name": "com.amazonaws.ecs.capability.docker-remote-api.1.18"
        },
        {
            "name": "ecs.capability.task-eni"
        }
    ],
    "placementConstraints": [],
    "compatibilities": [
        "EC2",
        "FARGATE"
    ],
    "requiresCompatibilities": [
        "FARGATE"
    ],
    "cpu": "512",
    "memory": "1024",
    "registeredAt": "2023-03-19T10:24:24.737Z",
    "registeredBy": "arn:aws:sts::account-id:assumed-role/...",
    "tags": []
}
```

I can see the env variable `AWS_CONTAINER_CREDENTIALS_RELATIVE_URI=/v2/credentials/something-something` inside container and trying to get list of s3 buckets using boto3 library but get **ListBuckets operation: Access Denied**

```
>>> session = boto3.session.Session()
>>> s3 = session.client("s3")
>>> s3.list_buckets()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/app/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/botocore/client.py", line 530, in _api_call
    return self._make_api_call(operation_name, kwargs)
  File "/app/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/botocore/client.py", line 960, in _make_api_call
    raise error_class(parsed_response, operation_name)
botocore.exceptions.ClientError: An error occurred (AccessDenied) when calling the ListBuckets operation: Access Denied
```

I can see the readonly access key and secret access key by running the following command but looks like I am missing something.

```
>>> print(session.get_credentials().get_frozen_credentials())
```

Just for testing I tried to follow the steps mentioned [here in AWS Guid for Task IAM role](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/task-iam-roles.html) to get the credentials and use them to communicate with the s3. I am able to get the credentials and can communicate with s3.

```
>> r = requests.get("http://169.254.170.2/v2/credentials/something-something")
>>> r.json()
{'RoleArn': 'arn:aws:iam::account-id:role/task-role', 'AccessKeyId': 'access-key-id', 'SecretAccessKey': 'secret-access-key', 'Token': 'very-long-token', 'Expiration': '2023-03-20T14:52:49Z'}
>>>
>>>
>>> s3 = boto3.client("s3", aws_access_key_id="access-key-id", aws_secret_access_key="secret-access-key", aws_session_token="very-long-token")
>>> s3.list_buckets()
{...}
```

Comment: Can you provide information of how did you assign the policy to your ecs task?

Comment: @Marcin I've updated my question with taskdefinition.json where I specify the `taskRoleArn` which have the policy mentioned above.

Comment: The policy you posted is for taskrole or execution role?

Comment: that is for taskRole

Comment: The bounty attracted a [ChatGPT](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/421831/temporary-policy-chatgpt-is-banned) plagiariser (not the only one with a bounty).

Comment: Does the bucket have a bucket policy?

Comment: If you have the current access key and secret key inside the container, can you test it from another client to check the permissions?